# Perl writes LF as CRLF on Windows

Tags: windows, perl

I have gotten some stray Windows-style line endings in a couple of files and I am trying to resolve it on my Windows machine with the following command:

```
perl -pi -e s/\R/\n/ example.txt
```

After running this all line endings in the files this was run on have been changed to CRLF, which is the opposite of my intention. Why is perl doing this, and is there anything I can change to make this work as I expect it to?

I am using Strawberry Perl version 5.28.

Comment: try install Msys ~109 mb https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbundle/files/latest/download ,  perl 5.28 ~51 mb , if add cpan ~281 mb.. easy linux \n newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows builds of Perl adds a `:crlf` layer to handles by default. This converts CRLF to LF on read, and LF to CRLF on write. (Some other languages do something similar.)

You need to tell Perl it's not a text file. Unfortunately, one can't do that with ARGV, the special handle you are using.

```
perl -pe"BEGIN { binmode STDOUT }" example.txt >example.new.txt
move example.new.txt example.txt
```

Comment: You could also use [`dos2unix`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/)

Comment: Yeah, initially it seemed easier since I already had Perl installed to run a simple substitution.

Comment: According to the [PerlIO docs](https://perldoc.pl/PerlIO), you could set `PERLIO=raw` in the environment to prevent the default crlf layer. Layers are *really* strange, and I don't have a Windows machine to test if it works.